# ARKit - why is camera zoomed in ARSCNView on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I have a simple ARKit app with a fullscreen ARSCNView. When ran on an iPhone, the camera view is not zoomed, however when ran on an iPad (12.9" iPad Pro), the camera view is zoomed in, and I am unsure why.

I have constraints in place to make the ARSCNView be the size of the available screen, but I suspect the zoom may be something to do with constraints?

[image]

Comment: Check the resolution of your view and the camera. Actually it is showing `aspectFill` that's why it is zoom for you. If you will use the same ratio for example `16:9` then it will be correct.

Comment: That didn't make any difference I'm afraid, I tried Aspect Fit and Aspect Fill, no difference.

Comment: You don't have to change the content mode. Your `Camera Preset`'s resolution and `CameraView`'s resolution should be same.

Comment: How do I check / change those?

Comment: If you change the frame of `ARSCNView` `height:width` to `16:9` does it effect anything on zoom?

Comment: Could you please check [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportedVideoFormats](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2942261-supportedvideoformats) ... it might help you.